# Redirects based on file folder structure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

We have an website whose url structure is undergoing major changes.  As there are lots of pages, I am trying to find a method that redirects based on the requests file structure AND the lack of a file extension.

The webpages are primarily one of two version:

- mydomain.com/some-page-title
- mydomain.com/multiple/folder/levels/some-other-page

The end goal is:

- mydomain.com/some-page-title.htm
- mydomain.com/newfolder/some-other-page.htm

I know I can assign a condition to point to a specific redirect for the second example, as in the upper code block.  And I can do a simple redirect for the first example.  But disappointingly both rewrites effect the urls with multiple/file/folders structure and I end up with two redirects, one with the new folder and one with the original folders.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/multiple/$1 -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^multiple/folder/levels/(.*)$ /learn/$1.htm [R=301,NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.htm [R=301,NC,L]
```

Is there RewriteCond that says CAN NOT contain a specific file structure?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may try these rules that won't affect each other:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (?:/|\.[a-z0-9]{3,4})$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^multiple/folder/levels/(.+)$ /learn/$1.htm [R=301,NC,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/learn/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.htm [R=301,NE,L]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/learn/ [NC]` will prevent second redirect rule to execute after first redirect.

Make sure to clear browser cache or use a new browser for testing this change.